# How to Update node in spatial layer in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I used spatial features of Neo4j. I faced following problem in that. I used Node API to create a node and add that node to Spatial Layer.

Que 1 :- In Neo4j Browser client when i retrive all node it shows me two node with same node no. (One is real node and other is added to spatial layer). I think second node is for indexing purpose. Need clerification on this. I am wrong or it's bug or it's normal behaviour.

Que 2 :- If I update latitude and longitude of real node then second node in spatial layer is not updated with new value of co-ordinates. How can i update both node?

Any Help will be very helpful for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Neo4j spatial adds a second node within the geo R-Tree that represents the location of your domain node.
2. You have to remove it from the index and re-add it again.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. 
I am not able to remove node from index. I used following API to delete node from index. But after this API also node is still in Spatial Layer.

http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/kvnode/kvkey2/90

Can I delete complete layer and recreate it. But according to following link deleting complete layer is still not implemented. 

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.neo4j.user/20461

Please guide me in proper direction.

Answer (score 0):

1. As @Michael pointed correctly, it's a normal behavior as it's a representation of location of your node.
2. To remove a node from an index, you can delete the node, using "internal" id of the indexed node. Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409461/neo4j-spatial-what-is-the-official-way-to-delete-a-node-from-a-spatial-index/36763527#36763527), for the detailed steps on how to do that. After that you can easily re-add the node to index.