# neo4j-spatial: What is the official way to delete a node from a spatial index?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-spatial

My question is most certainly a duplicate of [Neo4j Spatial - How To Delete A Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105667/neo4j-spatial-how-to-delete-a-node), but it has not yet been solved.

To my understanding removing a node from a spatial index is currently not implemented (not documented) within the neo4j-spatial-plugin.

**Now my questions would be:** "How do I do this myself?" I can see all the nodes of the index, but how do I query that very node that refers to the node I want to delete? And furthermore: May I just delete that node from the index without harming anything else?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You are correct. As [this link](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial/issues/139) says,this is a known issue and its still open since very long.

Now, coming to your question, you can do it manually by following the below steps.

### Get the internal `"id"` property of the indexed node, which you want to delete.

1. Whenever any node is added to index (let's say 'geom'), then a `UNIQUE RTREE_REFERENCE` is added with that node. `NEO4J` assigns a unique id to that reference. This assigned "id" is different than the "id" which was used to index the node.e.g. Let's consider that "User" node with `id:7577` is added to  index "geom", using `localhost:7474/db/data/node/7577`.
2. Now, after this index is created, you can check it's `RTREE_REFERENCE`, with the following command in Neo4j Browser.`MATCH (a)-[:RTREE_REFERENCE]->(b) where b.id=7577 return b;`
3. We need to get the "internal" id of the node "b", we can do this by firing below command in the Neo4j Browser. `MATCH (a)-[:RTREE_REFERENCE]->(b) where b.id=7577 return id(b);`

### Delete the Node from index using "internal" ID

1. Let's say from above step, we get 7578 as the "internal/actual" id.
2. Now, we can fire a curl command manually on the server as below
   curl -X DELETE http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/geom/7578

### Cross-Verify in Database

1. Now, if you re-query from Neo4j browser,using the below same query `MATCH (a)-[:RTREE_REFERENCE]->(b) where b.id=7577 return id(b);` you will get "no rows". as the `RTREE_REFERENCE` has been deleted.

**Note :** *All of the above steps can be automated from your code too, using any HttpClient from Java/.Net/PHP.*

Hope this answers both of your questions

Thanks